# OVH VPS (Ubuntu 18.04) can not connect with IPv6

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ipv6, netplan

I have a VPS server from OVH running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS  and I noticed today that the IPv6 was not working at all, nor was the IPv6 assigned to me listed when I looked in ifconfig. Then I followed the OVH guide [here](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/vps/configuring-ipv6/) and I followed the section for my version of Ubuntu and edited my netplan accordingly. However, although I can see my IPv6 address when I type ifconfig, it does not establish a connection when I attempt to ping an ipv6 address or make any other connections with IPv6. I have followed the guide exactly and made sure I had followed it properly so I am not sure why it's not working and would appreciate any help on what I'm missing with this. I have pasted my 51-cloud-init-ipv6.yaml below (2001:db8:555:555::2a11 represents my assigned IPv6 address in the OVH control panel and 2001:db8:555:555::1 represents the gateway)

```
network:
version: 2
ethernets:
    ens3:
        dhcp6: false
        match:
            name: ens3
        set-name: ens3
        addresses:
          - "2001:db8:555:555::2a11/128"
        gateway6: "2001:db8:555:555::1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work! The problem was that when I inputted my IPv6 address as instructed, it could not communicate with the gateway as I had put the prefix as /128, thus leaving the client and gateway on different subnets. I changed /128 to /64 and now all is working.